# Are there functions to know if two columns data are equal?

Tags: mysql

There is a query :

```
select
    CONCAT_WS(' ',column_1,column_2) as col 
from table_1 as t1
inner join table_2 as t2 on t1.pk = t2.pk;
```

I want to make the concatenation only if colum_1 != colum_2 , otherwise column_1 is just selected.

Is there MySQL functions which permit to know that `column_1 = column_2` ?

Comment: have a look at MySQL's if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` statement for the two alternatives:

```
select
  case
    when colum_1 != colum_2 then CONCAT_WS(' ',column_1,column_2)
    else colum_1
  end as col
from ...
```